# Android GridView custom Layout with variable height and width for each cell

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

Is it possible to create a grid view where each cell can have a variable width and height?.

I have tried this libraries:

- https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView

But they only allow me to change the Heigh or the Width of a cell, you cannot change both.

This is an example for iOS of how to do that, but I cannot find the solution for Android.

This it what I want to do:

[image: What I want to do in Android]

https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout

Is there a way to do that in Android? I have tried almost everything.